# TextMate - jump to latest modification

Tags: textmate

is there any way of quick jump to the last modified line? eclipse has it bound to ctrl-q and I find it very usefull while navigating between multiple files. for example, when i need to check something in other file, with ctrl-q i'm able to return immediately to the place where I was writing something before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always just use command-z + command-shift-z.  It's a bit kludgy, but it works.

Note that there was a discussion about this very issue on the TextMate Users mailing list just a few days ago.  They came to the same conclusion.  [Here's the thread on GMANE](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.textmate.general/29721)

**Update:** Hans-Jörg Bibiko from the mailing list has created a full-fledged plugin that adds a "Go to Last Edit" menu item in the Navigation Menu, and is mapped to ⌥⌘J by default.  [Here's his new thread on the topic.](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.textmate.general/29831)